# ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE or "cannot parse response" in iOS

Tags: nginx, ios

I'm getting `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` on Safari and "cannot parse response" from Chrome on my iOS device, but Windows, Android, Linux Desktop all work fine. Why?

I migrated a WordPress site from an Ubuntu Apache server to an Arch Nginx-Apache reverse proxy server.

- A fresh installation WordPress site worked on the new server.
- The migrated WordPress site got this error.
- A fresh installation of PostfixAdmin also got this error on the same NA-rp configuration.

What is causing this, and what is the solution? Is it a PHP problem? Most answers on the web recommend resetting the rouder, checking DNS records, and flushing the cache, but none of this helps. For example:

- [Cannot Parse Response in Safari? Here's How to Fix](https://appuals.com/cannot-parse-response-safari/)
- [How to Fix: Cannot Parse Response in Safari Browser?](https://browserhow.com/how-to-fix-cannot-parse-response-in-safari-browser)

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was the `Update` header from Nginx, ***not HTTP/2**!!*

[This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70022093/10343144) led me to this [other answer on SF](https://serverfault.com/a/975885/487033), which was not the accepted answer. Many note that it comes from HTTP/2. But, while the problem may exist inside HTTP/2, turning off HTTP/2 wasn't the answer, but only hiding the `Upgrade` header in Nginx.

Inside this statement:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

}
```

Added this line:

```
   proxy_hide_header Upgrade;
```

Resulting in:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_hide_header Upgrade;

}
```

I'm posting my own answer, but I'd love more info from others.

No one still knows why the iOS stack alone has this problem, [for example](https://serverfault.com/a/819331/487033):

> but I still cannot understand why it's happing ONLY WITH devices iOS 10.